# Send email from server via a G Suite email address

Tags: node.js, gmail, gmail-api, nodemailer, google-workspace

I am attempting to send an email from a node.js server using `nodemailer`

I currently have a domain name registered with Google Domains and with this I have a G Suite instance setup to provide me with an email server.

I have an email setup: `noreply@domainname.com`

What im trying to do is send an email from email above from my server. I don't want to use plain user and password verification as this is very insecure for me.

Does anyone have a tutorial or document they could link me to that would help me achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) from the official [Gmail API documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/).

> Complete the steps described in the rest of this page, and in about
>   five minutes you'll have a simple Node.js command-line application
>   that makes requests to the Gmail API.

Snippet from the quickstart:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Gmail API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listLabels);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the labels in the user's account.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listLabels(auth) {
  var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
  gmail.users.labels.list({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var labels = response.labels;
    if (labels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No labels found.');
    } else {
      console.log('Labels:');
      for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        var label = labels[i];
        console.log('- %s', label.name);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

To understand the concept and the implementation details, you can try [Sending Email](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending). To give you an overview, here is the way of sending email and high end workflow.

> There are two ways to send email using the Gmail API:
>
> - You can send it directly using the [**`messages.send`**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send) method.
> - You can send it from a draft, using the [**`drafts.send`**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send) method.
>
> Emails are sent as base64url encoded strings within the raw property
>   of a [message resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages). The high-level workflow to send an email
>   is to:
>
> 1. Create the email content in some convenient way and encode it as a base64url string.
> 2. Create a new message resource and set its **`raw`** property to the base64url string you just created.
> 3. Call **`messages.send`**, or, if sending a draft, **`drafts.send`** to send the message.

You can also refer to this tutorial from [Nodemailer community site](https://community.nodemailer.com/).

> These docs apply to the unmaintained versions of Nodemailer v2 and
>   older. For an upgraded and up to date Nodemailer v3+ documentation,
>   see nodemailer.com homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building whole logic for creating tokens you can simply use [Passportjs google auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth) and then finally use the googleapis package to send emails.